# Convert user input decimal to integer

Tags: c#

Complete newbie in programming but trying to write a program where the user inputs a decimal and it gets turned in to the closest integer.

Here is my code, I'm guessing I have the conversion all wrong?

```cs
Console.WriteLine(" Write a Decimal: ");

double decimalTal = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
double helTal = Math.Round(decimalTal);

Console.WriteLine(helTal);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Define closest..

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert class

```
System.Convert.ToInt32(dNumber);
```

please refer to Microsoft documentation
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=net-5.0)